# Need a better way to find the tag to use in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

This is my code which save the heading of [www.nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com) in a .txt file.

Using requests and beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")

with open(str(input("Please enter a file name: ")), "w") as f:
   for i in soup.find_all('p'):
      if i.a: 
         f.write(i.a.text.replace("\n", " ").strip())
      else: 
         f.write(i.contents[0].strip())
```

In the code this line:

```
for i in soup.find_all('p'):
```

Which is suppose to find all heading does't work. It just takes a few first heading not all.

Is there any better way to write this line rather than going to website then inspect and then to find the tag which hold the content which i need.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because the web page is dynamic, that is why your 'html.parser' does not give you all headings. Try to use [selenium](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/guide-scraping-dynamic-web-pages-python-selenium) module to scrape dynamic web pages.